# data not stored in laravel back end from axios post of vue js front end

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have some data that i need to store in my database coming from localStorage. One is an input field where a user can change the quantity of an item, the other is a radio box where the user has to select an address to deliver to. The issue is that it just won't store the address_id in my database nor update the qty field of the input in my cart. Could someone take a look at it and explain why this doesn't work? I'd appreciate it so much thanks!

Note: The data object is reactive, I checked in my vue dev tools and it changes the data correclty so no issue there.

Vue add to cart button component:

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="addToCart">
        <button>Add to cart</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['productId', 'categoryId'],
    data() {
        return {
            product: {},
            cart: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
       fetchData() {
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/product/${this.productId}/category/${this.categoryId}`)
                .then(res => {
                    const { product } = res.data;

                    this.product.id = product.id
                    this.product.title = product.title;
                    this.product.fitSize = product.fit_size;
                    this.product.jeansSize = product.jeans_size;
                    this.product.price = product.price;
                    this.product.img = product.images[0].images;
                    this.product.quantity = 1;
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        },
        addToCart() {

            if(localStorage.getItem('cart')) {

                // Little note to myself: 
                // Grab data from local storage and turn it into a js array of objects
                // Push new product to that array every time the addToCart method gets fired
                // get that array with the additional items and store back in local storage as a JSON string
                let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
                cart.push(this.product)
                return localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
            } else {
                this.cart.push(this.product)
                localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.cart))
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchData()
    }
}
</script>
```

Vue checkout component:

```
<template>
    <div> 
            <div v-for="product in products" v-bind:key="product.id">
                <p>Img: {{product.img}}</p>    
                <p>Title: {{product.title}}</p>    
                <p>Price: {{product.price}}</p>  
                <input v-model="product.quantity" type="number" name="qty" id="qty">
                <br>
            </div> 

            <form method="POST" @submit.prevent="placeOrder">

                <div v-for="address in user.addresses" v-bind:key="address.id">
                    <input type="radio" v-model="addressId" v-bind:value="address.id" name="address_id" id="address_id">{{address.street}}
                </div>

                <button>Place order</button>
            </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['user'],
    data() {
        return {
            products: null,
            addressId: null,
            orders: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchDataFromLocalStorage() {
            this.products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
        },
        createOrders() {
            this.products.forEach(product => {
                this.orders.push({
                    qty: product.quantity, 
                    user_id: this.user.id, 
                    product_id: product.id,
                    address_id: this.addressId
                })
            })
        },
        placeOrder() {
            const sendOrders = { orders: this.orders }
            axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/api/user/${this.user.id}/checkout`, sendOrders)
                .then(res => console.log(res.data))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchDataFromLocalStorage();
        this.createOrders();
    }
}
</script>
```

Laravel store method:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {

        foreach ($request->orders as $order) {
            Order::create([
                'qty' => $order['qty'],
                'product_id' => $order['product_id'],
                'user_id' => $order['user_id'],
                'address_id' => $order['address_id']
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json('Order created');
    }
```

Order model:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }

    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Addresses::class);
    }
}
```

Laravel api route:

```
Route::post('/user/{id}/checkout', 'CheckoutController@store');
```

Tinker when I make a post request:

```
      App\Order {#3072
         id: "127", 
         qty: "1",   // Default value just won't change whenever I try to update it!
         delivered: "0",
         product_id: "3", // This works
         created_at: "2019-12-23 10:08:09",
         updated_at: "2019-12-23 10:08:09",
         user_id: "1", // This works
         address_id: null, // This doesn't
       },
     ],
```

Comment: Please can you show the code you have in your `Order` model as well.

Comment: You probably are not allowing those two fields to be mass assigned.

Comment: @Rwd this is the model  `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Product;
use App\User;
use App\Addresses;

class Order extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class);
    }

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }

    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Addresses::class);
    }
}
`

Comment: @HelderLucas I've left the array of the protected $guarded property empty in my Order controller so it should be fine...

Comment: The logic you've shown is only creating new orders (not updating them)

Comment: @Rwd Yes I know, that's exactly what it should do. There are no orders in the db, it just has to create new ones from scratch. It's the whole poin :)

Comment: You have nothing in the `$fillable` array? the `Create::`  method requires all of your props to be fillable.

Comment: @Joe Hi Joe, doesn't leaving protected $guarded = []  empty do the same?

Comment: I was under the impression that an empty `$guarded` array does not mean everything is fillable. Try adding `qty` to your `$fillable` array.

Comment: @Joe Just did, still the same issue, this has been going all day :). Am gonna go trough every step and see whether there is something I've missed somewhere. Thanks anyway, have a good one.

Comment: What do you get if you `dd($order);` inside the foreach loop of your controller's `store` method?